# How do I remove the middle top corner and border of selectable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm new to fabric js and trying to change the style of selectable.
I want to customize the Selectable.

Before the CSS was (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkrs0.png)
I changed it to
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN7QR.png)

The code i wrote for this is

```
            this.canvas.getActiveObject().set({
                borderColor: '#6B8BFF',
                borderDashArray: [10, 5],
                cornerColor: '#FFFFFF',
                cornerStrokeColor: '#6B8BFF',
                cornerSize: 10,
                cornerStyle: 'circle',
                transparentCorners: false,
            });
```

And the style I'm trying to achieve is

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h86hz.png)

I need to remove the top middle corner and border that is extra in my case. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

According to fabric js [docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setControlsVisibility) you can disable middle-top-rotate control like this:

```
this.canvas.getActiveObject().setControlsVisibility({
    mtr: false
});
```